# Умножение в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица **`apartments`** (квартиры), у которой есть поля **`total_area`** (общая площадь) и **`price`** (цена за 1 квадратный метр).

Задача написать функцию, которая будет делать выборку из таблицы **`apartments`** записи, у которых полная цена попадает в диапазон цен (цены передаются параметром).

Т.е. если написать в виде обычной формулы записи должны подходить под условие `price * total_area > total_price_min && price * total_area < total_price_max`.

Собственно вопрос, как можно реализовать подобное, ведь в MySQL нельзя умножать если я не ошибаюсь?

Вариант сделать выборку, а потом отсеять записи, не подходящие под условие, не подходит, мне нужно чтобы результат запроса к БД содержал список, подходящий под условие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MySQL можно умножать.

```
SELECT * 
FROM apartments 
WHERE price * total_area BETWEEN total_price_min AND total_price_max
```